# GAS onFormSubmit trigger returns after first console.log

Tags: google-apps-script

Problem: for some users I can only see the first logToConsole(). Then it seems that the function returns without throwing an error or anything else.

What I have checked / tried so far:

- Google Form saved in Shared Drive vs. My Drive
- Creating new forms

```
function onSubmitInst(event) {
    logToConsole('onSubmitInst start'); // Is logged

    var form, docProps, valueStatus, formLimits, realFormValueCell, mailFormStatus, formTitle;

    try {
        docProps = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    } catch (error) {
        logToConsole('onSubmitInst property error'); // Is NOT logged
        return;
    }

    form = event.source;
    formTitle = form.getTitle();

    mailFormStatus = docProps.getProperty('mailForm');

    formLimits = docProps.getProperty('formLimits');
    formLimits = formLimits ? JSON.parse(formLimits) : {};

    logToConsole('onSubmitInst OK'); // Is NOT logged

    // ... more code ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()` returns a valid [`Properties`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties) object if the script is published as an add-on or it is bound to a document. Else it returns `null`.

Either way, it will not trigger your `try -> catch`, `null` returns are not exceptions and does not generate error messages.

You would have to check the returned object if `null` or valid and adjust your logic accordingly.

```
    docProps = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    if (docProps === null) {
        logToConsole('onSubmitInst property returned null');
        return;
    }
```

**References:**

[Class Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getDocumentProperties())

Comment: Hi Carlos, Thank you for looking into my issue. The try/catch part is a GAS specific implementation from me. There are situations where PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties() is not allowed to call because of missing permissions. This is the reason why I have done this. Maybe my post was not clear enough: there is no error within try/catch and there is no error within the whole onSubmitInst() function.

Comment: You can still place your try/catch, but you should also check if the return value of ````PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties() ```` is null. Null return is not an error.

Comment: If it would return null then this line would throw an error: mailFormStatus = docProps.getProperty('mailForm');

Comment: Then I think you would need to so some debugging to check where your code stopped. Given that this is within an installable trigger, it would be helpful to place log statements on each statement and see where it stops. Also try logging your docProps variable to verify if it returns null or not.

Comment: I think it is a GAS bug, because only ~3% of my users are experiencing this.

Comment: If you think this is a GAS bug please create a ticket in issuetracker.google.com